# Encrypted data in debug log

Tags: visualforce

In here
[Encrypted fields](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm&language=en)
it says

> Data for encrypted fields in the debug log is masked

I have this page

```
<apex:page standardController="account" extensions="ext" >
<apex:form >
<apex:outputfield value="{!account.password__c}"></apex:outputfield>
</apex:form>
```

and extension class

```
public class ext {
apexpages.standardcontroller sc1;
public ext (apexpages.standardcontroller sc)
{
 sc1 = sc;
 account a = (account)sc1.getrecord();
 system.debug(a.password__C);
}
}
```

when i look at debug log ,i can see

> 16:16:47.062 (62513108)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[7]|System.debug(ANY)
>   16:16:47.062 (62533903)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|DEBUG|hijkl

Can see unmasked value is being displayed .
(i dont have view encrypteddata permission enabled and my page does display this field masked)

why is this so?

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be a bug of some sort; I was able to replicate it. *Generally*, the system does protect against encrypted data exposure. Here's some things I tried:

```
// Execute Anonymous
Account record = [SELECT Id,Name,Encrypted__c FROM account where name = 'testx1234'];
String x = record.Encrypted__c;
System.debug(logginglevel.error, record);
System.debug(logginglevel.error, x);
System.debug(logginglevel.error, record.Encrypted__c);
```

Output:

```
13:58:40.030 (30791101)|USER_DEBUG|[3]|ERROR|Account:{Name=TestX1234, Encrypted__c=****, Id=0015000000u5QiWAAU}
13:58:40.030 (30828356)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|ERROR|****
13:58:40.030 (30861310)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|ERROR|****
```

I then tried the same concept using a controller:

```
public with sharing class accountCtrl {
    public accountCtrl(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        Account record = (Account)controller.getRecord();
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, record);
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, record.Encrypted__c);
        String x = record.Encrypted__c;
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, x);
        Account record2 =[SELECT Id, Name, Encrypted__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :record.Id];
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, record2);
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, record2.Encrypted__c);
        x = record2.Encrypted__c;
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, x);
    }
}
```

The output here was different:

```
13:57:37.124 (124467952)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|ERROR|Account:{RecordTypeId=01250000000QNyFAAW, Encrypted__c=****, Id=0015000000u5QiWAAU, IsPersonAccount=false}
13:57:37.124 (124533149)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|ERROR|ABCD
13:57:37.124 (124564371)|USER_DEBUG|[7]|ERROR|ABCD
13:57:37.129 (129214484)|USER_DEBUG|[9]|ERROR|Account:{Name=TestX1234, RecordTypeId=01250000000QNyFAAW, Encrypted__c=****, Id=0015000000u5QiWAAU}
13:57:37.129 (129260562)|USER_DEBUG|[10]|ERROR|ABCD
13:57:37.129 (129290380)|USER_DEBUG|[12]|ERROR|ABCD
```

The moral of the story is that, depending on the execution context and means of accessing the record, explicitly debugging the *field* may result in data exposure, but debugging the *record itself* should obscure the text.

---

### Edit

After more testing, I came up with this code:

```
// Execute anonymous
Account record = [SELECT Id,Name,Encrypted__c FROM account where name = 'testx1234'];
record.Encrypted__c = 'BCDE';
String x = record.Encrypted__c;
System.debug(logginglevel.error, record);
System.debug(logginglevel.error, x);
System.debug(logginglevel.error, record.Encrypted__c);
```

Which had the output:

```
14:04:57.034 (34482749)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|ERROR|Account:{Name=TestX1234, Encrypted__c=****, Id=0015000000u5QiWAAU}
14:04:57.034 (34525409)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|ERROR|BCDE
14:04:57.034 (34575783)|USER_DEBUG|[6]|ERROR|BCDE
```

It would appear that tainting only occurs at certain points in the lifecycle, and that Visualforce context provides less protection than Execute Anonymous. The only guarantee that I could find is that debugging the record itself always encrypted the text value, but debugging just the field or a copy of the field value often resulted in data exposure.